# asymptote function project cause problem with scaling

Tags: asymptote

When I used asymptote function `project` I met some strange problem with picture scaling. So, here is an example:

```
import three;
settings.render = 0;
size(8cm,0);

path3 p1 = unitsquare3;

triple T1 = (0,0,0);
triple T2 = (0.8,0,0);
path3 t = T1 -- T2;

transform3 s1 = shift((0.3,0.2,0)) * rotate(65,(0,0,1));
transform3 s2 = shift((0.1,0.5,0)) * rotate(-20,(0,0,1));

path3 b_1 = s1 * t;
path3 b_2 = s2 * t;

draw(project(p1)); 
draw(project(b_1));
draw(project(b_2));
label("$\beta$",(0.95,0.95,0),N);
```

So, we can see such result:
[image]

Let us change the code above:

```
draw(p1); 
draw(b_1);
draw(b_2);
```

And we can see:[image]

Let us change again this code:

```
draw(project(p1)); 
draw(b_1);
draw(project(b_2));
```

And we can see now the third picture:

[image]

Change again:

```
draw(p1); 
draw(b_1);
draw(project(b_2));
```

In this case we can see the second picture again:

[image]

How to explain such strange behavior of function `project`?

Comment: It seems that the objects drawn with`project(path3)` do not respect the size constraint. It means that asymptote does not take it into account for the final and automatic size of the picture. `project` is used in `three.asy` but through the deferred drawing. At last : why do you use `project` ?

Comment: Thank you (I've not enough rep to estimate your comment). This is 'stripped' example from experiments with **geoespace** module.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the viewpoint from being adjusted by inserting after `import three;` the line

```
currentprojection=perspective(1,1,1,autoadjust=false);
```

Comment: I tried to use ``currentprojection=perspective(5,4,2,autoadjust=false);`` and this method doesn't work for me. The types of pictures look like in the pictures of question.

Comment: In any case, thanks, and if I can force your method to work, I'll appreciate the answer.